# Inheritance example explanation, coding and methods, etc?

Tags: java, inheritance

I don't understand inheritance, at all. 
From what I've read, inheritance means a subclass or child class can "inherit" or retrieve? the methods and values from its parent/ super class.

And I sort of understand [this example](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/java-basics/java-inheritance-example/), but it's still not very clear to me.

If I were to put an if statement in animal, do bird and dog, get an if statement as well?

Here is the actual code, I didn't finish the last portion for main class, because it was somewhat clear to me.

Also what exactly is `System.out.println()` doing in main class, is it printing all the strings?

And how come when I run the classes separately nothing actually prints out, but when I run main class, everything prints?

```
public class Animal {
public Animal() {
    System.out.println("A new animal has been created!");
}   
public void sleep() {
    System.out.println("An animal sleeps...");
}
public void eats() {
    System.out.println("An animal eats...");
}
}
```

then bird

```
public class Bird  extends Animal {

public Bird() {
    super();
    System.out.println("A new bird has been created!");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public void sleep() {
    System.out.println("A bird sleeps...");
}
public void eats() {
    System.out.println("A bird eats...");
}

}
```

then dog

```
public class Dog extends Animal {

public Dog() {
    super();
    System.out.println("A new dog has been created!");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
public void sleep() {
    System.out.println("A dog sleeps...");
}
public void eats() {
    System.out.println("A dog eats...");
}
}
```

then this main class

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    Bird bird = new Bird();
    Dog dog = new Dog();

    System.out.println();
}

}
```

Comment: `"how come when i run the classes separately nothing actually prints out...."` -- how are you "running" the classes without a main method. Perhaps you're confusing **compiling** a class with ** running** one?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels: and moreover, I think you cannot run a class without main method, right? He must have been getting some exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I will try to explain in simplest way:**

`Animal` is the `super class`.

Every `animal` `sleeps` and `eats` so the methods are in the `super class`

When you create the objects of the specific animals.

```
    Animal animal = new Animal();
```

Calls the constructor of `Animal` prints :

```
System.out.println("A new animal has been created!");

    Bird bird = new Bird();
```

Calls the constructor of `Bird` following `super()` goes to constructor of `Animal` so prints both `sysouts`

```
    Dog dog = new Dog();
```

And simillarly with the `Dog`

**what exactly is System.out.println() doing in main class??**

It literally does nothing. If you remove it, the code will still print.
Try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply puting, if one 'extends' animal class to cat's class, cat's class inherits all the animal's class methods. This means you don't have to write  those methods twice since, like any animal, a cat eats, sleeps, walks, and so on...
then you can write down specifc methods in cat's class, like purr !( or maybe you want a class for mammals, and a class for felines tath inherits from those...

Answer (score 0):

`how come when i run the classes separately nothing actually prints out, but when i run main class, everything prints?`

A JAVA code requires `main` method to start its execution. So when you run other classes, it won't find the main method and so it does not print anything.

In `inheritance` only the variables and methods which you declare are inherited (passed on) to the sub class. The other things are of no matter for sub class.

For example:
Consider the relationship between you and your dad. Your dad is the super class here and you are the sub class. You have some all properties of your dad but they might not be the same. Like you have your eyes same as your dad, but their color may be different. An `if` statement can be considered as any decision that your dad took but you don't have to take that decision, so it is irrelevant to you.

`System.out.println();` in `mian` does not do anything extra. You can remove it.

I hope this helps you a bit. If you have any questions, do ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance give an '**IS A**' relationship. A dog **IS A** animal. A bird **IS A** animal.

If a class inherits from another class, it means it will be able to call the methods in that class as if they are its own.

One use which you will learn about is **Polymorphism**. One example is the ability to iterate through a list of Animal objects, each of which can be an Animal, Bird or Dog, call the methods of the superclass, and Java will redirect the call to the appropriate class at runtime. So if you have a for loop in the main class, you can do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
Animal animal = new Animal();
Bird bird = new Bird();
Dog dog = new Dog();

ArrayList<Animal> animalList = new ArrayList<Animal>();

animalList.add(bird);
animalList.add(dog);

//for each animal in the animal list
for(Animal : animalList){
    sleeps();
    eats();
}
```

This code will output the sleeps and eats calls for bird and dog objects, through the one list of Animals.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

```
public class Cat extends Animal {
    public Cat() {
        super();
        System.out.println("A new cat has been created!");
    }
}
```

Then in main,

```
Cat cat = new Cat();
cat.eats();
```

This will print "An animal eats...". Cat has the eats() method from Animal because it extended Animal. That example makes a little more sense to me because the method it's inheriting is not overridden.

Answer (score 0):

So pretty much with the example you gave, I'll tackle the easy question first. The System.out.println(); statement in the main method is just printing an empty line. Now onto explaining what each section of the code does.

```
Animal animal = new Animal();
```

This section of code creates an Animal object and calls the constructor.

```
public Animal() {
    System.out.println("A new animal has been created!");
}
```

Next called is
    Bird bird = new Bird(); 
This creates a Bird object and calls the constructor.

```
public Bird() {
    super();
    System.out.println("A new bird has been created!");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

What super() does is it calls the constructor of the super class, in this case the super class is Animal. With this in mind the output of the bird constructor should be

```
    A new animal has been created!
    A new bird has been created!
```

Since bird has its own sleep and eats method the Animal method gets overwritten.
The output for bird.eat() would be

```
    A bird eats...
```

likewise the output for bird.sleep() would be

```
    A bird sleeps...
```

Like when the Bird was created when Dog dog = new Dog(); is called it created a Dog object and calls the constructor, since the Dog class extends Animal when the Dog constructor is called it first calls the super classes constructor and then continues with Dogs constructor. This will occur even without the call to super();. The Dog class like the bird class shown earlier also overwrites the .eat() and .sleep() methods that it inherits from its super class and behaves in the same manor.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the System.out.println() in your main class only prints a new line.
This method takes a string argument (or no argument as above) and prints the string followed by a new line, this way you don't have to manually enter the new line escape code (\n I believe) every time you print a new line. System.out.print() does the same thing but it doesn't make the new line.

In the sample output, the System.out.println() from main.java is the blank line in between "A new dog has been created!" and "An animal sleeps..."

Everything else is printed in the methods, ex: System.out.println("A dog eats...");
Try replacing System.out.println("A dog eats..."); with System.out.print("A dog eats...\n");
It should have the same output if \n is indeed the correct escape for a new line.
Notice I changed "println" to just "print" and added \n to the end of the string.

The reason why nothing happens when you run anything but your main class is because main(String[] args) is the initializing method.  This is what is being looked for when your program runs.  Think of it as the ignition to your code - with no ignition, where does the computer put the key to start the program?  You can probably change this in your settings, but I wouldn't worry about that for now

I think you should try to understand these concepts before moving to inheritance, as they involve the basic flow of your code and how your output is produced.